# Helpers don't auto refresh with every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and recently I noticed this happening. 
All code that I write in a controller 
eg. class Xyz < ApplicationController...
gets refreshed with every request. Any change I make in the code in this class is reflected in the next request without restarting the server.

But any code I write in a class that does not < from ApplicationController 
or a class that is in the "helpers" directory does not get auto-refreshed.

Is this normal behaviour ? Because its a pain to restart the server every time.

I am using the following in development mode :

ruby 2.0.0

Rails 4.1.8

and thin server. (also happens with webrick)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , basically I had created a rails-api project..that did not have the "helpers" folder by default. I had created it myself(I forgot to mention that above) ... So basically adding this line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app)
```

to application.rb/development.rb(depending on your need), solves this issue.
you can add :

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

as well if you want to autoload everything in your "lib" directory.

Hope this helps the next person.

Answer (score 0):

The code changes to the helpers, controllers and models are picked up the application as we refresh the page but some times it behaves weirdly and we have to restart the server.